# bit shift operation on the status variable for IPC::Run

Tags: perl, cpan

I recently came across the following code for one of the perl module

```
  my @cat = qw( cat );
  use IPC::Run qw( run timeout );

   eval { run \@cmd, '<', "in.txt", \&out, \&err or die "cat: $?" };
  #here why status variable is being done Binary Shift Right
  my $status = $? >> 8;
```

I am unable to make why binary shift has been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am unable to make why binary shift has been made.*

Because you don't get the information you want if you don't.

`$?` contains three pieces of information:

- What signal killed the process (`$? & 0x7F`)
- Was a core dump produced (`($? >> 7) & 1`)
- Was error code was passed to `exit` (`$? > 8`)

Answer (score 0):

It's to allow for 'nesting' of return codes.

So you can tell the difference between `cat` generating an error code, and `run` generating an error code (or whatever perl call you're making).